# I want to pass row index as props to a child component that has camera. Vue is showing some warning. what is the problem?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props

[image: Invalid props type check failed for prop.]

The parent component pass the index to showCamera function which assign the index to pointerProps that is passed down to child component binding to camRowID.
Parent Component

```
                               </thead>
            <tbody class="table-body">
                <tr v-for="(row, index) in newRows" :key="index">
                    <template v-for="(item) in row" :key="item._ID">
                        <td>{{ item }} </td>
                    </template>
                    <td><input type="text" :name="row._ID" v-model="rowComment[index]"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="checked[index]" ></td>
                    <td><button @click="showCamera(index)"></button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
        <div class="geo-location">
          <div class="home">
            <div v-if="errorStr">
                Sorry, but the following error occurred: {{errorStr}}
            </div>
        
            <div v-if="gettingLocation">
                <i>Getting your location...</i>
            </div>
            <div v-if="location">
                <p>GPS Coordinates: {{location.coords.latitude+', '}}{{location.coords.longitude}}</p>
            </div>
            <button id="send-button" @click="postList()">Send</button>
            <p>{{rowComment + ' ' + checked}}</p>
            </div>
        <div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div v-if="getCamera">
        <camcom  @startcamera="startCamera" :camRowId="parseInt(pointerProps)"/>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import camcom from './CamCom.vue'
//import Api from '@/services/api/HttpCommon'
export default {
    components: {
        camcom
    },
    data() {
        return {
            columns: {},
            rows: [],
            newRows: [],
            pointerProps: null,
            responsiblePerson: '',
            stream: null,
            ready: false,
            photo: null, 
            location: null,
            gettingLocation: false,
            errorStr: null,
            geoLocation: {
                gpsLatitude: '',
                gpsLongitude: '',
            },
            checked: [],
            getCamera: false,
            rowComment:[],
            imageData: [],
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.getList();
        this.getLocation();
    },
    beforeMount(){
        this.trigger++;
    },
    methods: {
                showCamera(index)
        {
            this.getCamera = !this.getCamera;
            this.pointerProps = parseInt(index);
            //console.log(typeof this.pointerProps);
        },
```

Child Component
This component has props and type definition. The vue is showing some warning.  The props is successfully passed and is working. I am worried about the warning. what can be the issue?

```
<template>
<div class="contentarea">
    <div class="camera">
        <video id="video" ref="video">Video stream not available.</video>
        <button id="startbutton" @click="takePhoto">Take photo</button>
        <canvas id="canvas" ref="canva"></canvas>
        <div class="output">
            <img id="photo" alt="The screen capture will appear in this box.">
        </div>
        <button @click="getMedia()"></button> 
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
//import { number } from '@intlify/core-base';

import { number } from '@intlify/core-base';

export default{
    name:"camcom",
    props:
    {
        camRowId:
        {
            type: number,
            required: false,
        }
    },
    data(){
        return{
            dataPicture: [],
            counter: 0,
            streaming: false,
            canvas: '',
            stream: null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async getMedia()
        {
}}
```

Comment: Why this much `parseInt` for index ? Ideally, It should be number only.

Comment: I am trying two places to parseInt because it was/is showing the warning error.

Comment: Looks like your code is incomplete. Can you please post whole code ?

Comment: Rohit I have tried to put as much code possible. But the code related to problem is all here.

Comment: As `index` is a index for each iteration. hence it will be numeric only. Don't use `parseInt`

Comment: It shows that warning without use and with use. The program is working fine. I just wanted to make the warning go away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camRowId props type should be Number instead of number. Capital "N".